# Properties file on different path

Tags: java, path

I have a properties file named xyz.properties that is in the root folder of my Java Project. Now I want to change the location to some other place (say Desktop on Windows).

Is the properties file have to be on the root folder? Could my Java application read it from another location outside the project?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If properties file is on the classpath then it can be loaded using the generic code as mentioned here:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
```